# Euclidean Distance - Loop Function

Tags: python

I calculated 3-nearest-neightbor for point (0.5,0.5) using below formula:

```
## for the first record , here we show how to calculate the distance
distance2=(data.iloc[0,0]-0.5)**2+(data.iloc[0,1+1]-0.5)**2
distance2
distance=np.sqrt(distance2)
distance
data.iloc[0,3]=distance
```

There are 24 records in dataset. I calculated distance .156433 for first row (GPA - SAT) using above formula. How do I use loop function to repeat the same for another 23 rows:

```
         NORMALIZED_GPA   NORMALIZED_SAT  ACCEPT_NUM   distance
0           0.3500          0.4556           1         0.156433
1           0.6833          0.2889           1         0.000000
2           0.4111          0.7889           1         0.000000
3           0.3722          0.7111           1         0.000000
4           0.7000          1.0000           1         0.000000
5           1.0000          0.5444           1         0.000000
```

Comment: `df.iloc[0,1+1]` accesses the first row and the `ACCEPT_NUM` column, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what want to do? You typically don't need to use an explicit loop with pandas data. Arithmetic operations on columns will apply to every row in the dataframe. This is called "vectorized operations".

```
data.distance = (
    (data.NORMALIZED_GPA - 0.5)**2 + 
    (data.NORMALIZED_SAT - 0.5)**2
)**0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find the Euclidean norm of `data.NORMALIZED_GPA - 0.5` and `data.NORMALIZED_SAT - 0.5`:

```
data.distance = ((data.NORMALIZED_GPA - 0.5) ** 2 + (data.NORMALIZED_SAT - 0.5) ** 2) ** 0.5
```

a more efficient method would be to use the [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) method:

```
data.distance = math.hypot(data.NORMALIZED_GPA - 0.5, data.NORMALIZED_SAT - 0.5)
```